# How is this JMH microbenchmark skewed, if it is?

Tags: java, jit, microbenchmark, jmh

The benchmark is quite simple:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class MathPowVsRawMultiplyTest
{
    private static final double VICTIM;

    static {
        VICTIM = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextDouble();
    }

    double result;

    @Benchmark
    public void mathPow()
    {
        result = Math.pow(VICTIM, 2.0);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void rawMultiply()
    {
        result = VICTIM * VICTIM;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws RunnerException
    {
        final Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(MathPowVsRawMultiplyTest.class.getCanonicalName())
            .forks(1)
            .warmupMode(WarmupMode.BULK)
            .warmupIterations(1)
            .measurementIterations(1)
            .build();

        new Runner(options).run();
    }
}
```

Of course, the environment matters, a lot, so here goes:

- this main() is run through IDEA 15.0.1;
- Ubuntu 15.10, x86_64;
- Oracle JDK 1.8u65;
- machine is a Dell M3800, 16 GiB RAM, 8 CPU cores and the first paragraph from `/proc/cpuinfo` follows.

The cpuinfo:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4712HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x1c
cpu MHz         : 3235.722
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
bugs            :
bogomips        : 4589.60
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

And the result of the benchmark:

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt           Score   Error  Units
MathPowVsRawMultiplyTest.mathPow      thrpt       2342955236.832          ops/s
MathPowVsRawMultiplyTest.rawMultiply  thrpt       2375082332.164          ops/s
```

What I haven't done is try and see what optimizations the JVM could do for `Math.pow()`; but the result seems pretty close.

The problem is that I don't know JMH that much, therefore I wonder: is my benchmark completely flawed, or is the CPU/JIT combination that good?

Comment: Both of them are taking almost exactly 1 clock cycle per operation so Dead Code Elimination must be happening. Try returning the result instead.

Comment: Also make the input less inlineable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your benchmark is completely flawed, because compiler is able to constant-fold loads from `static final` fields. Have you read at least the first few samples, notably [JMHSample_10_ConstantFold](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/bcec9a03787f/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_10_ConstantFold.java) and [JMHSample_08_DeadCode](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/bcec9a03787f/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_08_DeadCode.java)? This is how it is done better (but not actually verified, *caveat emptor*):

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class MathPowVsRawMultiplyTest {
    private double v;

    @Setup
    public void setup {
        v = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextDouble();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public double mathPow() {
        return Math.pow(v, 2.0);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void rawMultiply() {
        return v * v;
    }
}
```

You are also advised to set the timeunit to nanoseconds (see `@OutputTimeUnit` or `-tu`), and switch to average time measurement instead of throughput (see `@BenchmarkMode` or `-bm`). Also, for the nanobenchmarks like these, you *need* to verify the difference in the compiled code, available with `-prof perfasm`, for example.

Comment: I fail to see how the fact that the field is static final matters; in fact this is what I want: I want to test the raw performance of Math.pow() vs multiply. So it makes sense that I should have a single value, no?

Comment: `static final` is treated as the constant, and the computations that use that as the argument are folded at the (JIT) compile time. Read the JMH samples I posted, and play with them?

Comment: I will read your examples carefully... Well, again, since I have already read them and cannot figure out what you're trying to say. For instance, why return the value in the individual benchmarks?

Comment: Because DCE is tricky, and avoiding it is not as simple as a plain field store. Let JMH do it for you.

Comment: OK, so, how does returning the result on the benchmark differ from using a JMH `BlackHole`?

Comment: Not to mention it deviates from the JMH instructions of dealing with the issue... It differs a great deal. `Blackhole` has an entire "Implementation Notes" section on that. For example: `@Benchmark` method inlines, external loop unrolls two times, first operation does the effectively dead store, boom.